# Getting data from a web service using AngularJs. Am I doing it in the correct way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, ionic-framework

I am using following codes to get data from a webservice.

I want to know that it is a correct way ,Is there any other better way to do this and also how can i handle the error.?

My factory object to get dada from a services

```
.factory('userSubCat', function($http,$rootScope) {

return {
    getSubs: function(){
  return $http.post('http://xxxx.com/demo/app-api/subcategory.php', {"categoryId":$rootScope.catIdSelected}).then(function(response){
          return response;
        });
    }
}
})
```

I have included the following code to show the loading icon

```
$scope.loadingIndicator = $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading Data',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: false,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 500
});
```

I am consuming the data as mentioned below

```
 userSubCat.getSubs().then(function(data){

             $scope.playlists =data.data.subcategoryList;

             $scope.loadingIndicator.hide();

        });
```

I want to know that it is a correct way ,Is there any other better way to do this and also  how can i handle the error?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question: Please edit your code and clarify where and how you call the function userSubCat.getSubs().

Regarding your second question: To get aware of errors when using $http use the following signature:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have modified the code to call the web services.

Comment: Looking at your edited code: if you expect 'userSubCat.getSubs()' to return a promise, then it should be sufficient to call 'return $http.post('http://xxxx.com/demo/app-api/subcategory.php', {"categoryId":$rootScope.catIdSelected})' in your factory. Then you are able to handle the successCallback and the errorCallback in your controller.